# Android SQLite database error when try to insert into table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my project ,add a function to insert elements to data base in a class `public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` .The function is given below.

```
public void insertIntoDatabase(String field_one,String field_two){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO UserTable.NAME (COL_USERNAME, COL_PASSWORD) " +
            "VALUES (" + field_one + ", " + field_two + ")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
```

In main activity read name and password and call the function insert into database

```
DBHelper dbhelper;



dbhelper.insertIntoDatabase(rdname.getText().toString(), rdpwrd.getText().toString());
```

But there was an error .

Comment: "But there was an error ." ... really descriptive (add logcat and what the error tells)

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: error at    dbhelper.insertIntoDatabase(rdname.getText().toString(), rdname.getText().toString());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I pretty recommend to you use API method of SQLiteDatabase `db.insert()` that is directly designated for inserting new rows to table. This solution is cleaner.

```
public void insertIntoDatabase(String field_one, String field_two){
   ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
   data.put("COL_USERNAME", field_one);
   data.put("COL_PASSWORD", field_two);
   if (db == null) {
      // make sure that your db is properly initialised
   }
   db.insert("tablename", "nullColumnHack", data);
}
```

Explanation of **nullColumnHack:**

> If your provided values is empty, no column names are known and an
>   empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack
>   parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly
>   insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.

It means that in `Android SQLite` you have to specify one column that will be assign `NULL` to in the case if you pass empty ContentValues.

If you want to use your approach i recommend to you an usage of placeholders.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO UserTable.NAME (COL_USERNAME, COL_PASSWORD) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?)";
    db.execSQL(sql, new String[] {field_one, field_two});
```

**Note:** Probably it didn't work because you didn't use **single quotes**.

```
VALUES ("' + field_one + '", "' + field_two + '")"
```

And also make sure that given tablename is correct. I recommend to create static variables which will hold tablename and column names.

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Table";
String query = "insert into " + ClassName.TABLE_NAME + " values(?, ?)"
```

Comment: what if all i have in a table is just the _ID , and I want to add an empty row into it? what should I put into the parameters of the insert() ?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql string doesn't separate your static variables from the rest of your SQL statement. This should fix it:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + UserTable.NAME + "(" + COL_USERNAME + "," + COL_PASSWORD ") VALUES (" + ...
```

Just make sure that UserTable.NAME is the table name and that is has fields named exactly the same as the values of COL_USERNAME and COL_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO UserTable.NAME (COL_USERNAME, COL_PASSWORD) " +
             "VALUES ("+'" + field_one + "', '" + field_two + "'+")";
```

Values of column should be in `''` single quoted string....